# GPA Calculator troubles

Tags: python, computer-science

For some reason that is unknown to me, my GPA calculator only calculates the last input in the list, I only have 2 days left to complete this and hopefully i can in time.

I tried to make it to where it calculates every input nd not just the last one, but i dont know how.
here is my code:

```
name = input("What is your name? \n")
h1 = ("Class Name")
h2 = ("Class Grade")
h3 = ("Credit Hours")
point = input("\nEnter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):\n")
class_data = []
while point != "Done":
    words = point.split(" ")
    if len(words) == 1:
        print("Error: No spaces in string. Try again.")
    elif len(words) > 4:
        print("Error: Too many spaces in input. Try again. ")
    else:
        try:
            class_name = words[0]
            grades = (words[1])
            hrs = int(words[2])
            print("Name of class:", class_name)
            print("Grade:", grades)
            print("Class Hours:", hrs)
            class_data.append((class_name, grades, hrs,))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Space not followed by an integer.")
    point = input("\nEnter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):\n")

    def gpa_calculator(grades):
        points = 0
        i = 0
        grade_c = {"A":4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3.0,"B-":2.67, "C+":2.33,"C":2.0,"C-":1.67,"D+":1.33,"D":1.0,"F":0}
        if grades != class_data:
            for grade in grades:
                points += grade_c[grades]
            gpa = points / len(grades)
            return gpa
        else:
            return None 

print("Name: ", name)
print("-" * 66)
print("%-15s|%11s|%5s|" % (h1, h2, h3))
print("-" * 66)
for item in class_data:
    print("%-15s|%11s|%12s|" % (item[0], item[1], item[2]))
print("-" * 66)
print('Your projected GPA is: ',(gpa_calculator(grades)))
print("-" * 66)
```

here is the output :

```
What is your name? 
John Smith

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
poop D 50
Name of class: poop
Grade: D
Class Hours: 50

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
poop D 50poop D 50poop D 50
Error: Too many spaces in input. Try again. 

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
poop D 50
Name of class: poop
Grade: D
Class Hours: 50

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
poop D 50
Name of class: poop
Grade: D
Class Hours: 50

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
perfecgt A 1
Name of class: perfecgt
Grade: A
Class Hours: 1

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
Done
Name:  John Smith
------------------------------------------------------------------
Class Name     |Class Grade|Credit Hours|
------------------------------------------------------------------
poop           |          D|          50|
poop           |          D|          50|
poop           |          D|          50|
perfecgt       |          A|           1|
------------------------------------------------------------------
Your projected GPA is:  4.0
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code and found a few quirks in the code.  First off, the variable "grades" is just a single variable within your program and is not defined anywhere as a list.  That seemed to be the main point of contention with the code.  It appears that you want to extract the second element within the class_data list to determine a dictionary value.  With that, I tweaked the code a bit, specifically in the gpa_calculator" function.  Following is your code with the tweaks.

```
name = input("What is your name? \n")
h1 = ("Class Name")
h2 = ("Class Grade")
h3 = ("Credit Hours")
point = input("\nEnter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):\n")
class_data = []
while point != "Done":
    words = point.split(" ")
    if len(words) == 1:
        print("Error: No spaces in string. Try again.")
    elif len(words) > 4:
        print("Error: Too many spaces in input. Try again. ")
    else:
        try:
            class_name = words[0]
            grades = (words[1])
            hrs = int(words[2])
            print("Name of class:", class_name)
            print("Grade:", grades)
            print("Class Hours:", hrs)
            class_data.append((class_name, grades, hrs,))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Space not followed by an integer.")
    point = input("\nEnter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):\n")

    def gpa_calculator(grades):
        points = 0
        i = 0
        grade_c = {"A":4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3.0,"B-":2.67, "C+":2.33,"C":2.0,"C-":1.67,"D+":1.33,"D":1.0,"F":0}
        if grades != class_data:
            for item in class_data:         # Need to read through the class data list to acquire grade element for each class
                # print(item[1])
                points += grade_c[item[1]]  # Grade is the second element in each grade_list entry
            gpa = points / len(class_data)
            return gpa
        else:
            return None 

print("Name: ", name)
print("-" * 66)
print("%-15s|%11s|%5s|" % (h1, h2, h3))
print("-" * 66)
for item in class_data:
    print("%-15s|%11s|%12s|" % (item[0], item[1], item[2]))
print("-" * 66)
print('Your projected GPA is: ',(gpa_calculator(grades)))
print("-" * 66)
```

Testing it out provided the following sample output.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/GPA$ python3 GPA.py 
What is your name? 
John Smith

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
History D 40
Name of class: History
Grade: D
Class Hours: 40

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
Physics C 20
Name of class: Physics
Grade: C
Class Hours: 20

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
Math A 20
Name of class: Math
Grade: A
Class Hours: 20

Enter your class name followed by your letter grade and hours (say Done to stop input):
Done
Name:  John Smith
------------------------------------------------------------------
Class Name     |Class Grade|Credit Hours|
------------------------------------------------------------------
History        |          D|          40|
Physics        |          C|          20|
Math           |          A|          20|
------------------------------------------------------------------
Your projected GPA is:  2.3333333333333335
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That appears to be the output you are expecting.

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the input you give to the function, `grades` this variable will be changed and then added to `class_data` in the tuple but it will keep just one value, meaning it will keep the last value it was given and calculate the gpa with just that. Instead you should give a list so it can iterate through all the values.
Here is what I changed and for the case you gave give the right output 1.75

```
def gpa_calculator(grades:list):
    points = 0
    grade_c = {"A":4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3.0,"B-":2.67, "C+":2.33,"C":2.0,"C-":1.67,"D+":1.33,"D":1.0,"F":0}

    for x in grades:
        if x[1] not in grade_c:
            return "ERROR"
        points += grade_c[x[1]]
    gpa = points / len(grades)
    return gpa
gpa_calculator(class_data)
```

EDIT: I did not comment the code assuming that you would understand what the problem was. If you have any question pls comment it.

EDIT2: Also you should define the function at the begining of the line not indented, check [PEP8 Python Style Guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested out your code and it seems it's mostly working. I noticed that you send the variable `grades` into the `gpa_calculator` function, but not the `class_data` item (which includes all the data which you want to average over). Try to do this at the end:

```py
# ...

def gpa_calculator(grades):
    points = 0
    grade_c = {"A":4,"A-":3.67,"B+":3.33,"B":3.0,"B-":2.67, "C+":2.33,"C":2.0,"C-":1.67,"D+":1.33,"D":1.0,"F":0}
    
    for grade in grades:
        points += grade_c[grade[1]] # get middle item in tuple (name, grade, hrs), equals the 
    gpa = points / len(grades)
    return gpa

# ...
print('Your projected GPA is: ',(gpa_calculator(class_data))) # noticed I changed this to class data, not grades
# ...
```